# How to replace GNU core utilities with Busybox

Tags: busybox, coreutils

I was wondering: is it possible to replace the GNU coreutils with Busybox in Ubuntu? Is that safe? Could I replace something else (like binutils and bash) with Busybox? How much free disk space would I get with that? And, if plausible, how could I do that?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible. Busybox on Ubuntu doesn't support the full set of utilities that coreutils provides. Examples include `base64`, `comm`, `install`, `nohup`. Packages can safely use programs installed by `coreutils` without depending on it as a package, since it's [an **essential** package](https://askubuntu.com/a/13591/158442); there's no telling what coreutils commands a package might be using. You could try building Busybox from source, since [the full set of commands](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) do include `install`, `comm` and `nohup`, and `uuencode`/`uudecode`, which could server as an alternative to `base64`. However, even *that* has missing commands like `groups`, `paste`, `nproc`, `truncate`, etc.

---

You could try. Do something like:

1. Symlink `/bin/busybox` to the coreutils commands which are supported by `busybox`.
2. Install [a placeholder `coreutils` package](https://askubuntu.com/q/18192/158442) with a higher [epoch number](https://askubuntu.com/q/441879/158442) than the Ubuntu coreutils package, so that a package upgrade will never happen for coreutils.
3. Install only those binaries from the actual `coreutils` package which Busybox didn't support.
4. Hope that the system doesn't crumble. Get used to manually upgrading coreutils commands when the package gets patched.

---

It's also not possible to replace bash or binutils. Bash offers a far richer syntax than Busybox ash. And as far as I can tell, binutils has nothing in common with Busybox.

---

Ubuntu just isn't the system you want, if you're *that* concerned with space. Look at some of the alternatives mentioned in [this Super User post](https://superuser.com/q/307087/334516).